# not working jquery show/hide by dropdown

Tags: jquery, show-hide, dropdown

not working jquery show/hide by dropdown when there are many dropdown with same class or id.
when change dropdown affects all elements.
please help me

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".gatewayname").hide();
     $(".bankname").show();
    $(".paytype").on("change", function() { 
  var val = $(this).val();
           if (val === "bank"){
                $(".gatewayname").hide();
                $(".bankname").show();
            }else{
                $(".gatewayname").show();
                $(".bankname").hide();
            }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><select name="paytype" class="paytype"><option value="bank">Bank</option><option value="online">Online</option></select>
        <br><br>
        <select class="gatewayname"><option value="paypal">Paypal</option>option value="Card"></option>Card</select><br>
        <input type="text" name="bankname" class="bankname"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><select name="paytype" class="paytype"><option value="bank">Bank</option><option value="online">Online</option></select>
        <br><br>
        <select class="gatewayname"><option value="paypal">Paypal</option>option value="Card"></option>Card</select><br>
        <input type="text" name="bankname" class="bankname"></td>
</tr>
            
            
<tr>
<td><select name="paytype" class="paytype"><option value="bank">Bank</option><option value="online">Online</option></select>
<br><br>
<select class="gatewayname"><option value="paypal">Paypal</option>option value="Card"></option>Card</select><br>
<input type="text" name="bankname" class="bankname"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kralpc/yae753Lw)

Answer (score 2):

you need to use **$(this)**  ,**closest()** and **find()**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".gatewayname").hide();
     $(".bankname").show();
    $(".paytype").on("change", function() { 
        var val = $(this).val();
           if (val === "bank"){
                $(this).closest('td').find(".gatewayname").hide();
                $(this).closest('td').find(".bankname").show();
            }else{
                $(this).closest('td').find(".gatewayname").show();
                $(this).closest('td').find(".bankname").hide();
            }
    });
});
```

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/yae753Lw/1/)**

or you can use **$(this)** and **nextAll()**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".gatewayname").hide();
     $(".bankname").show();
    $(".paytype").on("change", function() { 
        var val = $(this).val();
           if (val === "bank"){
                $(this).nextAll(".gatewayname").hide();
                $(this).nextAll(".bankname").show();
            }else{
                $(this).nextAll(".gatewayname").show();
                $(this).nextAll(".bankname").hide();
            }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/yae753Lw/2/)

Comment: @Kral - please accept this answer to indicate to other readers that this answer solves your specific question.